# Node.js e Express - TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express.js

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro no console: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Estou lendo o livro "Mean Full stack Javascript..." da casa do código. Durante o desenvolvimento da aplicação apresentada no livro, obtive o erro acima. O que estou tentando fazer é salvar ou atualizar um determinado dado em uma lista, por enquanto estática, no servidor. Porém, depois de passar pelo AngularJs(rotas e controller) e chegar no Express o controller recebe o objeto enviado como undefined.

Dando uma pesquisada, alguns lugares indicaram dá uma olhada no body-parser, mas aqui está tudo ok, com base no livro e no que a galera aconselhou em outros pots. Contudo, não consegui resolver o problema. Segue os códigos abaixo:

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="salvar()" >
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome">Nome Completo</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" name="nome" required ng-model="contato.nome">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" required ng-model="contato.email">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    <a href="#/" class="btn btn-default">Voltar</a>
</div>
```

**Controller AngularJS**

```
var Contato = $resource('/contatos/:id');

        $scope.salvar = function(){
        $scope.contato.$save()
            .then(function(){
                $scope.mensagem = "Contato salvo com sucesso!";
                $scope.contato = new Contato();
            })
            .catch(function(erro){
                console.log(erro);
            });
    };
```

**Rota Express**

```
var controller = app.controllers.contatoController;

    app.route('/contatos')
        .get(controller.listaDeContatos)
        .post(controller.salvarContato);

    app.route('/contatos/:id')
        .get(controller.obtemContatoPorId)
        .delete(controller.remover)
        .post(controller.salvarContato);
```

**Controller Express**

```
    controller.salvarContato = function(req, res){
    console.log("Chegou até salvarContato!");
    var contato = req.body;
    console.log(contato);
    contato = contato._id ? atualiza(contato) : adiciona(contato);
    res.json(contato);
}
```

Em suma. O objeto chega no express undefined... Já revisei a parte do livro que explica sobre, já procurei na net, até que desisti e vim aqui. rsrs

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda!

Pra não ficar de fora, deixo também a **configuração do body-parser**.

*ps: o nome do modulo requerido esta da mesma forma da dependencia no arquivo package.json*

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

Vlw!

Comment: O console expressa o erro na 5º linha do Controller do Express acima.

Comment: Jocsã, se fiseres `console.log(JSON.stringify(contato));` podes colocar aqui o resultado?

Comment: Olá @Sergio ! O resultado é undefined. Acredito que o objeto não é recuperado ao usar o req.body ou ele nem mesmo está sendo enviado através da requisição post.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(contato)` não deve dar undefined... O que dá `console.log(typeof contacto, contacto || 'vazio');`?

Comment: Identifiquei e corrigi o problema @Sergio , grato pela atenção!

Comment: Ok, se quiseres coloca a solução nas respostas. Se não é melhor fechar/apagar esta pergunta pois mais ninguém vai saber o que o problema foi nem a solução :)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui corrigir. O problema se encontrava no arquivo de configuração do express.

Estava chamando primeiro o express-load para importação dos arquivos antes de definir o body-parser. Apenas inverti a ordem das chamadas e a requisição funcionou.

O erro de fato era que o objeto não estava chegando no servidor devido ao body-parser não esta apto no momento necessário para fazer a conversão do Json para objeto e vice-versa.

Espero ter ajudado alguém com o meu problema!